# Independent, Dependent Variables, Nonlinear

Tags: regression, modeling

So, I am not a statistician, but a burgeoning mathematician.  Here is something that is perplexing me in statistics, however.  My apologies if the question is silly, on one hand, or just not solvable, on the other.  Also, any online resources would be helpful.  I am looking to learn:

Let's say we have independent variables $ x_1, x_2, ..., x_n $, the dependent variable $y$ and the function $ y = f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) $

Say, further, that the variables $x_1, ..., x_n $ are a function of time --- $x_j = x_j(t)    \forall j$ --- meaning $y = f(x_1(t),...,x_n(t))$

Given $m$ time samples of all variables, if we believe the relationship is linear, we may form  the $ m \times n $ matrix $A$ whose $j$th column is given by the values of $x_j(t)$ at the $m$ time-values.  Using ordinary least-squares, we may find an $\bf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that minimizes
$$ \| \bf{y} - A \bf{z} \|_2 $$
where $\bf{y}$ is the vector of time-samples of $y$.

However, what if we don't believe the relationship between $y$ and the $x_j$s are  linear (or only linear with some), or what if a linear fit is terrible?  Given the data and no other information, how can one test for such a thing?  What are alternatives to ordinary least squares when we don't have information about the underlying pdfs or variances?  Are there functions built in R or scipy (python) for such a question?

Comment: I was somewhat confused by the introduction of the time series element, which complicated the considerations. Are you just looking for [nonlinear regression/nonlinear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression)? Or are you after some nonlinear time series model (and if not, why mention the time index if it's not doing anything but adding observations)? In any case, you can do either in R; `nls` is built in (it's in `stats`, so just type `?nls`), nonlinear time series would require you to download a suitable package.

Comment: Yes, this is a start. Thank you.  I do not know statistics.  I was just modeling the situation as I went.  You are right -- in a certain sense, the time itself is irrelevant -- but I do not know what a nonlinear time series model is, obviously, so I don't know how to answer your question.

Comment: If your observations aren't related over time (e.g. related because $y(t)$ is correlated with $y(t-k)$ or with earlier $x$'s), you probably don't need to worry.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to test whether or not a time-series is non-linear, yes, you can do that. There are numerous tests and one popular test is called the BDS test. A good reference is [Modelling Nonlinear Economic Time Series by Timo Teräsvirta, Dag Tjøstheim, and Clive W. J. Granger](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199587148.001.0001/acprof-9780199587148). By the way, time does matter, in the sense that the *order* of the data is important anyway.